# Show me a way to sort a char vector in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, alphabetical

I'm doing this exercise from DCoder, and I'm trying to solve it in C++. But I need a little help. Although I know this should be simple, I just seem to miss something.

I'm given 2 inputs, the first one is the number of letters that will follow, and the second input is these letters. I need to write a code that will give an output of the letter array in alphabetically sorted order.

Example input:

```
5
Z k a P b
```

Expected output:

```
a b k P Z
```

Can any of you guys show me what the simplest way is to solve my problem?

I tried the `std::sort()` function in many ways, but it's not helping me much.
Is the `std::sort()` function even a good way to sort something like this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char s;
    vector<char> vec;

    while (cin >> s){
        vec.push_back(s);
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    for (int i = 0; i <= vec.size(); i++){
        cout << vec[i] << " " ;
    }
}
```

My code is supposed to output `a c D M`, but it's giving `D M a c` instead.

Comment: Because uppercase ASCII characters sort before lowercase ones. Take a look at the ASCII character set - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: You'll need to implement a custom sort method that performs a comparison of characters after being converted to lower (or upper)

Comment: Should all lower case letters come before all uppper case letters?

Answer (score 1):

`std::sort()` will work fine, but note that it orders values in ascending order by default, and in ASCII uppercase letters appear before lowercase letters. To get around that, you can give `std::sort()` a custom comparator that performs a case-insensitive comparison, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

int main() {
    int n;
    char c;
    std::vector<char> vec;

    std::cin >> n;

    for (int i = 0; (i < n) && (std::cin >> c); ++i) {
        vec.push_back(c);
    }
    /* alternatively:
    std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), n, std::back_inserter(vec));
    */

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
        [](unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2){ return std::tolower(c1) < std::tolower(c2); }
    );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i){
        std::cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    /* alternatively:
    for (char c : vec){
        std::cout << c << " ";
    }
    */
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/1TFDsJ)

Comment: FWIW you could get rid of `my_tolower` and just use `[](unsigned char c1, unsigned char c2){ return tolower(c1) < tolower(c2); }`

Comment: @NathanOliver I thought about that initially, but I wasn't sure if the return values would compare correctly without being casted back to `char` first

Comment: The cast back is completely unneeded.  It wont affect the comparision.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that worked for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

//Compiler version g++ 6.3.0

char my_tolower(char ch)
{
    return static_cast<char>(tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)));
}

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    char c;
    vector<char> vec;

    for (int i = 0; (i < n) && (cin >> c); ++i){
        vec.push_back(c);
    }

    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [](char c1, char c2){ return my_tolower(c1) < my_tolower(c2); }
    );

    for (auto &&c : vec){
        cout << c << " ";
    }
}
```